# Installation of matplotlib using pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I wanted to install `matplotlib` on azure Virtual machine. And I don't have access to internet due to security reason.

I have followed as per below steps:

1. Downloaded matplotlib package from python index web portal
2. Executed `pip install matplotlib-2.1.0.tar.gz` from `conda` prompt, it gave me  `Failed building wheel for matplotlib` error

So I am trying to build Matplotlib on Windows Wheels via matplotlib-winbuild: https://github.com/jbmohler/matplotlib-winbuild

I have downloaded and extracted matplotlib-master, matplotlib-winbuild-master from github and executed `python matplotlib-winbuild\buildall.py` which needs Microsoft vs 2010 `C++` but I have already installed `Microsoft vs 2014 C++` as I am using `python 3.6`

I have searched and tried as per answers give in the below question, but they didn't help.

[Offline Installation of python & pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30181678/offline-installation-of-python-pip)
[Getting error while using pip installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45286577/getting-error-while-using-pip-installation)

I don't want to use conda to installed matplotlib due to proxy issues
What should I DO?

Comment: You can get wheels with binaries for windows on https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of downloading the `.tar.gz` (which contains the source code) you can download the `.whl` (which contains the compiled code) see [pypi page for matplotlib](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/matplotlib/2.1.2) for example.

Now you need to grab the correct build, you can easily see looking at the name, copying on the machine and installing like:

```
pip install whatever_lib.whl
```